# Different results when I change the dimension of the array but for the same equation?

Tags: c++, gcc

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and compiling my C++ code with `gcc`. When `m` and `n` values (which you can see in the code below) equal `6`, the printed `x` values are between `1` and `6`; and that's normal and correct; but the `y` values start with `7.0` and end with `12.0`. `y` values should also start with `1.0`, but when `m` and `n` equal `5`, I am not having the same issue. Both `x` and `y` values start with `1` end with `6`. Can anyone help me about that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#define m 6
#define n 6
using namespace std;

int main() {

    double f[8][n][m], feq, rho[n][m];
    double x[n], y[m], w[8], dx, dy;
    dx = 1.0;
    dy = 1.0;
    x[0] = 0.0;
    y[0] = 0.0; 
    int i,j;
    for (i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
        x[i] = x[i-1] + dx;
        printf("%f\n",x[i]);
    }
    for (j = 1; j < m+1; j++) {
        y[j] = y[j-1] + dy;
        printf("%f\n",y[j]);                
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant `for(i=1; i<n; i++){` and `for(j=1; j<m; j++){` you're off-by-one. `double n[6]` has 6 elements 0,1,2,3,4 and 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you meant to use `for(i=1; i<n; i++){` and `for(j=1; j<m; j++){`.

`double x[6];` has 6 elements 0,1,2,3,4 and 5.

This means that if you write to `n[6] = 6` you are encountering undefined behavior. In this case `n` and `m` happen to be next to each other in memory and when you write to `n[6]` you also write to `m[0]`. Although this is likely to happen with most C++ compilers you can not rely on this behavior. Since it's undefined by the C++ standard a compliant compiler does not need to make any guarantee as to what should happen in that case.

As to why this doesn't happen for you with `n` and `m` being 5. Well, since this is undefined behavior there doesn't need to be a consistency in behavior. It could be related to memory arrangement, so your compiler could order `x` and `y` differently in memory or add some padding in-between.